# Is it correct to say vertical conjunction?

Tags: ephemeris, conjunction

This question is related to this one: [Are we seeing a conjunction these mornings?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35159/are-we-seeing-a-conjunction-these-mornings/)

Last Feb 27, the a reporter said that, the day before, at sunset, Venus and the Moon were in vertical conjunction. Is that correct?

Sorry, but I cannot understand the meaning of near conjunction.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of "right ascension"?

Comment: @JamesK What is the relationship between 'right ascension' and 'conjunction'?

Comment: When two objects have the same right ascension, they are in conjunction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the evening of the 27th, Venus and the moon were not in conjunction. They didn't have the same right ascension.  However, from Europe they did have about the same azimuth, so would have appeared with Venus above a crescent moon in the sky.

This is, presumably, what the reporter meant by "vertical conjunction", but that is not a technical term.  And while this arrangement is pretty, it isn't very significant, and happens every month, when Venus is visible.